# Htaccess mod rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess

I use this code to rewrite

example.com/sample-file.php to example.com/sample-file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

How can i redirect this:

example.com/sample-file to example.com/sample-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add slash into your argument parameter, so it looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```